# How to reconcile these three definitions of an order?

Tags: order-theory, foundations

I have of late come across three definitions of a (total or partial) order and am not sure how to establish an equivalence among them.

Here's Definition 4.1-1 on page 210 in *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig.

> A *partially ordered set* is a set $M$ on which there is defined a *partial ordering*, that is, a binary relation which is written $\leqq$ and satisfies the conditions
>
> (PO1) $a \leqq a$ for every $a \in M$. (Reflexivity)
>
> (PO2) If $a \leqq b$ and $b \leqq a$, then $a = b$. (Antisymmetry)
>
> (PO3) If $a \leqq b$ and $b \leqq c$, then $a \leqq c$. (Transitivity)
>
> "Partially" emphasizes the fact that $M$ may contain elements for which neither $a \leqq b$ nor $b \leqq a$ holds. Then $a$ and $b$ are called *incomparable* elements. In contrast, two elements $a$ and $b$ are called *comparable elements* if they satisfy $a \leqq b$ or $b \leqq a$ (or both).
>
> A *totally ordered set* or *chain* is a partially ordered set such that every two elements of the set are comparable. In other words, a chain is a partially ordered set that has no incomparable elements.

Here's the definition of an order relation on page 24 in *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition.

> A relation $C$ on a set $A$ is called an *order relation* (or a *simple order*, or a *linear order*) if it has the following properties:
>
> (1) (Comparability) For every $x$ and $y$ in $A$ for which $x \neq y$, either $x C y$ or $y C x$.
>
> (2) (Non-reflexivity) For no $x$ in $A$ does the relation $x C x$ hold.
>
> (3) (Transitivity) If $x C y$ and $y C z$, then $x C z$.

Finally, here's Definition 1.5 on page 3 of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition.

> Let $S$ be a set. An *order* on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two properties:
>
> (i) If $x \in S$ and $y \in S$ then one and only one of the statements $$ x < y, \ \ \ x = y, \ \ \ y < x$$ is true.
>
> (ii) If $x, y, z \in S$, if $x < y$ and $y < z$, then $x < z$.

Now are these three definitions mutually in agreement? If so, how? Or, are there different schools of thought amongst mathematicians on this matter?

Comment: There are really two independent "axes" here: (1) is the ordering linear (i.e.  all elements are comparable), or partial (i.e. some pair of elements might be incomparable.). (2) is the ordering strict (so $a \not < a$ for all $a$) or not (so $a \leq a$ for all $a$).  That gives four options total, and those represent almost all uses of partial/linear orders.  In a few specialized contexts, other definitions are used - for example, in set theory we may assume only reflexivity and transitivity, but not antisymmetry.  You have to check each source to verify the assumptions being made.

Answer (score 2):

The last two are exactly the same.

In fact, you can rewrite $(1)$ as $$\forall x,y,\ (x=y\vee xCy\vee yCx)$$

And $(3)$ applied to $x=z$ becomes $$\forall x,y,\ ((xCy\wedge yCx)\rightarrow xCx)$$

So, since $xCx$ never holds by $(2)$, the statements $[x=y]$, $[xCy]$ and $[yCx]$ are mutually exclusive (i.e., $(i)$).

Of course, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are special cases of $(i)$.

Those two are *not* equivalent to the first one: for one thing, $((PO1)\wedge (2))\iff M=\emptyset$.

In fact, in the notation of the first definition (the one I've been taught, actually), a relation such as in the last two is called a *strict total order*. If it does not satisfy $(1)$, it's called "*strict (partial) order*" or, to be precise, you define a stirct partial order to be a relation $<$ satisfying:

- $[\forall x,y,z,\ ((x<y\wedge y<z)\longrightarrow x<z)]$
- $[\forall x,\neg x<x]$ (you can exchange this one with $[\forall x,y,\ \neg (x<y\wedge y<x)]$ and get an equivalent definition)

And a strict total order is a strict partial order satisfying $(1)$.

You can check that the following are equivalent:

> a) $R$ is a strict partial (total) order on $M$.
>
> b) $R$ satisfies $(2)$ and the relation $S$ defined by $$xSy\stackrel{\text{def}}\iff (x=y\vee xRy)$$ is a partial (total) order on $M$.
>
> c) there exists a partial (total) order $Q$ on $M$ such that $$\forall x,y,\ (xRy\longleftrightarrow (x\ne y\wedge xQy))$$

Comment: @CarlMummert there probably is a miswriting in my answer (I already found one, which I am about to correct), but I cannot find the one you said. Could you be a bit more precise as to where it is, so that I can correct it?

Comment: @CarlMummert Oh, ok. I was referring to the (1) in the second definition.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, that's what I meant. I agree it is imprecise, but I thought the analogy was clear.

Comment: Thanks. Probably it will make perfect sense to the OP.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is it true that one can view every non-strict partial order can be obtained from a strict partial order "plus" the equality relation?

Comment: @yumiko Yes because, for any strict partial order, the two non-strict partial orders cited in $(c)$ and $(d)$ are actually the same order. So, if you pick a "$\leqslant$", you obtain a "$<$" through $(c)$, and when you add to it the identical pairs as in $(b)$ you obtain again "$\leqslant$"